# Django Admin error using inline, please correct the errors below

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to Django and I'm currently leveraging the built in admin app. I am receiving the following error whenever I try to add/save an inline child group and whenever I do a simple edit to the parent:

please correct the errors below

If I don't include the inline...adds, edits and deletes work fine. I'm not too sure how to resolve this. I've tried a few things based on what is available via google search, but still have not come to a resolution.

Here is a snippet of my model:

```
class Group(models.Model):  # Parent
    groupid = models.CharField('Group ID',db_column='groupId', primary_key=True, auto_created=True, default=uuid.uuid4, max_length=36)  # Field name made lowercase.
    groupabbr = models.CharField('Group Abbr',db_column='groupAbbr', max_length=30)  # Field name made lowercase.
    groupname = models.CharField('Group Name',db_column='groupName', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.
    groupemail = models.EmailField('Group Email',db_column='groupEmail', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    # description = models.TextField(db_column='description', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(db_column='description', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    fkpripocpersonid = models.ForeignKey(Person,db_column='fkPriPocPersonId', related_name='priPocForGroups', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, max_length=36, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Primary POC')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fksecpocpersonid = models.ForeignKey(Person,db_column='fkSecPocPersonId', related_name='secPocForGroups', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, max_length=36, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Secondary POC')  # Field name made lowercase.
    primaryfieldtitle = models.CharField('Primary Field Title',db_column='primaryFieldTitle', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    primaryfieldcontent = models.TextField('Primary Field Content',db_column='primaryFieldContent', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    secondaryfieldtitle = models.CharField('Secondary Field Title',db_column='secondaryFieldTitle', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    secondaryfieldcontent = models.TextField('Secondary Field Content',db_column='secondaryFieldContent', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    createddate = models.DateTimeField('Date Created',db_column='createdDate', default=datetime.now())  # Field name made lowercase.
    createdby = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='createdBy', related_name='createdGroups', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, max_length=36,  null=True, verbose_name='Created By')  # Field name made lowercase.
    archiveddate = models.DateTimeField('Date Archived',db_column='archivedDate',
                                        default=datetime.now(), blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    archivedby = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='archivedBy', related_name='archivedGroups', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, max_length=36, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Archived By')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fkparentgroupid = models.ForeignKey('self', db_column='fkParentGroupId', related_name='Parents',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='Parent Group',
                                        max_length=36, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):  # this object's representation used throughout Django
        return self.groupabbr + ' - ' + self.groupname


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_group'
        ordering = ('groupname',)
```

Here is a snippet of my Admin.py:

```
class GroupInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Group
    classes = ['collapse']
    exclude = ['groupemail','primaryfieldtitle', 'primaryfieldcontent',
               'archiveddate', 'archivedby', 'createddate', 'createdby', 'secondaryfieldtitle',
               'secondaryfieldcontent',]
    """list_display = ('groupid', 'groupabbr','groupname', 'description', 'fkpripocpersonid', 'fksecpocpersonid',
                    'createddate', 'createdby') """
    list_editable = ('groupid', 'groupabbr','groupname', 'description', 'fkpripocpersonid', 'fksecpocpersonid',
                    'createddate', 'createdby')
    extra = 0



class GroupExistingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Group
    classes = ['collapse']
    exclude = ['groupemail','primaryfieldtitle', 'primaryfieldcontent',
               'archiveddate', 'archivedby', 'createddate', 'createdby', 'secondaryfieldtitle',
               'secondaryfieldcontent', 'groupid',]
    readonly_fields = ('groupabbr','groupname', 'description', 'fkpripocpersonid', 'fksecpocpersonid',
                       'createddate', 'createdby')
    extra = 0

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False


class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):
    list_display = ('groupabbr','groupname', 'fkparentgroupid', 'fkpripocpersonid', 'fksecpocpersonid')
    list_filter = ('groupname',)
    actions = ["export_as_csv"]
    inlines = [GroupExistingInline, GroupInline, ]
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ('fkparentgroupid', ('groupname', 'groupabbr'),
                           'description', 'groupemail', ('fkpripocpersonid', 'fksecpocpersonid',),  ('createddate',
                           'createdby'),)}),
        ('Primary Content', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),  # collapse, wide, extrapretty
            'fields': ['primaryfieldtitle', 'primaryfieldcontent', ],
        }),
        ('Secondary Content', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),  # collapse, wide, extrapretty
            'fields': ['secondaryfieldtitle', 'secondaryfieldcontent', ],
        }),

    ]


def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        self.form.admin_site = admin_site
        super(GroupAdmin, self).__init__(model, admin_site)


    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super().get_actions(request)
        if 'delete_selected' in actions:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions


admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

Comment: Hi! What is the error you're getting? It's unclear from the code you've given what is the error? Please paste the diagnostics or complete error message that django shows in the Browser-UI or terminal.

Comment: "please correct the errors below"....This is the only error I'm getting. Nothing else. It's very cryptic. Also, checked if there were any messages in my terminal window (in Pycharm IDE) and there was nothing.

Comment: I figured it out. I'm a little embarrassed about it because it was such an easy fix....sigh. My mistake was excluding groupid in GroupInline and GroupExistingInline